# How to use ldconfig to add pthread library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

Currently, while compiling a C program which uses pthread library function I have to specify compiler option -lpthread explicitly. Please suggest a way to configure ldconfig so that the pthread library could be used without specifying it on the command line.

presently lpthread -p gives the following output :=

```
[root@localhost lib]# ldconfig -p | grep pthread
    libpthread.so.0 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.9) => /lib/libpthread.so.0
    libOpenIPMIpthread.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libOpenIPMIpthread.so.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that. The LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ldconfig program are used to set up the paths to shared libraries that are used to resolve dependencies in your executable at *runtime*.

When compiling you will have to specify which libraries to include in the linking phase, i.e. -lpthread

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html) env variable.

Comment: Is there a way out without setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 0):

The pthreads library is a *dynamic library*.  This means that, in order to use its functionality, a file *distinct* from your binary must be available *at run time*.

You can do this in several ways.  Setting `-lpthread` will automatically set the compiler flags you want.  Providing the shared file via `LD_PRELOAD` will do the same.  Or you have your pthreaded program `dlopen` the library explicitly.

But the right way to do it is to provide the right compiler switches.